# How to resolve c++ source code to obj?

Tags: android, c++, assembly, webkit

I have source code:

```
RenderPart* Frame::ownerRenderer() const
{
    HTMLFrameOwnerElement* ownerElement = m_ownerElement;
    if (!ownerElement)
        return 0;
    RenderObject* object = ownerElement->renderer();
    if (!object)
        return 0;
    // FIXME: If <object> is ever fixed to disassociate itself from frames
    // that it has started but canceled, then this can turn into an ASSERT
    // since m_ownerElement would be 0 when the load is canceled.
    // https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18585
    if (!object->isRenderPart())
        return 0;
    return toRenderPart(object);
}
```

and objdump:

```
00143408 <_ZNK7WebCore5Frame13ownerRendererEv>:
  143408:       b510            push    {r4, lr}
  14340a:       f8d0 32f0       ldr.w   r3, [r0, #752]                                 
  14340e:       b14b            cbz     r3, 143424 <_ZNK7WebCore5Frame13ownerRendererEv+0x1c>
  143410:       6a1c            ldr     r4, [r3, #32]                                  
  143412:       b13c            cbz     r4, 143424 <_ZNK7WebCore5Frame13ownerRendererEv+0x1c>
  143414:       6820            ldr     r0, [r4, #0]                                   
  143416:       f8d0 30b0       ldr.w   r3, [r0, #176]
  14341a:       4620            mov     r0, r4
  14341c:       4798            blx     r3
  14341e:       b108            cbz     r0, 143424 <_ZNK7WebCore5Frame13ownerRendererEv+0x1c>
  143420:       4620            mov     r0, r4
  143422:       e000            b.n     143426 <_ZNK7WebCore5Frame13ownerRendererEv+0x1e> 
  143424:       2000            movs    r0, #0
  143426:       bd10            pop     {r4, pc}
```

Now I want to know which source code line can be compiled to 143416 line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is essentially `ownerElement->renderer`.

142312 is the last `if(!object)` (`return 0` is down at 143424-143426), then 143414-14341a are preparing for the function call `ownerElement->renderer()`:

143414 is getting ownerElement into r0

143416 is getting the offset for renderer() into r3

14341a is essentially setting the this ptr for use within renderer() (i.e. ownerElement)

14341c actually jumps to renderer()